# GCC error with -mcpu32 flag, CPU32 compiler needed

Tags: gcc

I am patching code into my car's ECU. This has a Motorola MC68376 processor, so I'm using the appropriate CPU32 instruction set.

I want to continue to write in assembly code so that I can explicitly manage control registers, RAM access and allocation, as well as copying code structures which are already in use.

My first patch was successfully compiled in EASy68k, but that program does not support the full instruction set for the CPU32. For example, the DIVS.L command is not supported, so I cannot take a quotient of a 32-bit value.

Thus, before writing my own compiler out of sheer incompetence with available tools, I'm looking for an easier path. I read that gcc has the capability to compile code for the CPU32, but I have failed to get it to work.

I'm using MinGW's gcc (6.3.0) and Eclipse (2020-03). I added the '-mcpu32' or '-march=cpu32' flags to the compiler call, according to:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/M680x0-Options.html

Unfortunately this returns an error:

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mcpu32'; did you mean '-mcpu='?

or

error: bad value (cpu32) for -march= switch

May I please have some advice for making this work? Does anyone know of a better CPU32 compiler that works with Eclipse?

Comment: Was your GCC compiled with CPU32 support? You need a cross-compiler here...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't realize that I had to do something special to make gcc have that functionality; I simply used what MinGW gave me, so it seems likely that it does not have the cross-compiler support. I'll see if I can figure out how to do that.

Comment: It seems that compiling gcc as a cross-compiler is not a trivial endeavor. I've found tutorials and shared scripts across the internet, but they are still not intuitive to someone without prior experience. The barrier to entry here is disheartening. Does anyone have constructive tips?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand that gcc is conventionally distributed as binary files that are compiled with different functionality to suit the needs of a given user.

There seem to be two paths forward:
1) compile my own cross-compiler version of GCC
2) download a pre-compiled cross-compiler version of GCC

I chose to follow route 2).

I began the process of installing the 'Windows Subsystem for Linux' and Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa, because I found a pre-made compiler that should be capable of performing cross compilation for the m68k processor: "gobjc-10-m68k-linux-gnu"

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/gobjc-10-m68k-linux-gnu_10-20200411-0ubuntu1cross1_i386.deb.html

While I was installing that, I also found an m68k-elf gcc toolchain that is pre-compiled for windows 10:
https://gnutoolchains.com/m68k-elf/

I played with the latter for much of today. Although I was unable to get the toolchain integrated well with Eclipse, it works from the command line to compile a *.s assembly code file. This includes compatibility with the '-mcpu32' flag that I wanted at the outset.

There is still a lot for me to figure out, even after floundering through learning gcc's assembler directives (https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs373/readings/Assembler.pdf) and the differences in gcc's assembly syntax compared to the MC68k reference manual (https://www.nxp.com/files-static/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf).

I can even convert the code section of the output file to be a proper s-record by using objcopy with the '-O srec' and '--only-section=.text' flags. This helps me patch the code into my ECU.

Thus I've answered my original question.